# Remotely logging a user into the console session?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, powershell, remote

I'm looking to remotely (preferably through PowerShell, but anything will do) log in a given user to the console session in Windows 10, ie, as if the user was sat at the computer and typed in their username/password.

At the moment the only way I can see of doing this is to create an RDP session with that user, then transfer the session to the console. I'm hoping there's some more elegant way of doing this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want a more elegant way, do you means you want a more user-friendly interface?  If so, you can look for a third-party remote login software to realize this.

Comment: @peter-g At the moment I've got it to work by starting an RDP connection, then running the script [here](https://superuser.com/questions/355935/how-can-i-restore-a-remote-desktop-session-to-the-local-console), By more elegant, I was hoping for a way to create the session directly on the remote computer without needing to create an RDP session first. The end goal is to have a PowerShell script used for deployment to automatically login and run a third-party GUI tool which the user enters some details in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell, but the user should be a member of "Remote Management Users" Group.

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername %Hostname% -Credential %Domain\username%
```

https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-without-administrator-rights/

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I'm looking to start a desktop session on the screen on the remote computer, not a PowerShell session.